# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSContactsUsageDescription?

Tags: ios

While fetching the contacts list using NSContactsUsageDescription, I am getting the below error.

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSContactsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

Also it was taking very long time to fetch the entire contact list in swift and in swift 3 there is this error.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sir my app is not rejected, it crashes. Thanks

Comment: @Rishi - the question is related to that question

Answer (score 1):

you will have to add the below key and values in your info.plist file.

```
key: Privacy - Contacts Usage Description 

Value: Allow Contact Access
```